# How to change color for some text in text view?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I made my homework for life cycle of view controllers. I used a tabbar to switch controllers. And when switching controllers, the label of text view to display life-cycle methods.

Now I want to change color text in text view for expression "First Controller", "Second Controller", "Third Controller" so that the colors remain the same regardless of which controller I switch to.

https://youtu.be/Od_bFlaA-kY

How to do it?

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var firstTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        FromCodeToScreen.shared.printMessage(textView: firstTextView, viewController: self)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        FromCodeToScreen.shared.printMessage(textView: firstTextView, viewController: self)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        FromCodeToScreen.shared.printMessage(textView: firstTextView, viewController: self)
    }

    // And similar code in all of the other lifecycle methods
}

import UIKit

class FromCodeToScreen: NSObject {
    static let shared = FromCodeToScreen()
    private var arrayForData = [String]()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func printMessage(textView: UITextView, viewController: UIViewController, function: String = #function) {
        arrayForData.append((viewController.title ?? "nil") + " - " + (function))
        let string = arrayForData.joined(separator: "\n")
        textView.text = string

        textViewScrollToBottom(textView)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change arrayForData string array to NSAttributedString.

```
class FromCodeToScreen: NSObject {

    static let shared = FromCodeToScreen()
    private var arrayForData = [NSAttributedString]()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    func printMessage(textView: UITextView, viewController: UIViewController, function: String = #function) {

        let color = viewController.view.backgroundColor ?? .white
        let attStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: viewController.title ?? "nil", attributes: [.foregroundColor : color])
        attStr.append(NSAttributedString(string: " - " + function + "\n"))
        arrayForData.append(attStr)
        textView.attributedText = arrayForData.reduce(into: NSMutableAttributedString()) { $0.append($1) }
        textViewScrollToBottom(textView)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: But I need different colors for text “First Controller, “Second Controller, “Third Controller”, For example First Controller - red, Second - violet, Third - green ! and when I switch between them, the colors are displayed which I set

Comment: @alexleo When you are in first view controller the whole text should be in red? and when you switch to second view controller the whole text should be in violet?

Comment: @alexleo if so just set firstTextView.textColor = .red in first view controller...

Comment: No! not whole, I want that the words "First Controller" to be red on all screens to which I switch, so that the words  "Second Controller" are also green in all screens and the same for words "Third Controller" - violet color

Comment: @alexleo and all function names in black color?

Comment: yes, all function names in black and names of title colors like your screen

Comment: In my func "printMessage" in the first two lines I get these errors 1.Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSAttributedString'. 2. Referencing instance method 'joined(separator:)' on 'BidirectionalCollection' requires the types 'NSAttributedString' and 'String' be equivalent

Comment: @alexleo delete FromCodeToScreen class from your project and copy FromCodeToScreen class from this answer

Comment: that is awesome, man, works perfect ! Many thanks! Please, can you explain how you change color ? I didn't see in your code where you set color and size of font ?

Comment: @alexleo I didn't change size of font. It uses default font of UITextView. I have changed color using NSAttributedString. Read this tutorial https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/attributed-strings-ios-tutorial

Comment: you specified attributes for  ".foregroundColor" just  name "color" ! but how you exact set color fo each controller ? because in the tutorial  that you sent( ioscreator.com/tutorials/attributed-strings-ios-tutorial ), I see how they change color, but I can't see in your code how to change

Comment: Check this line in the answer. It gets background color of corresponding viewcontroller. let color = viewController.view.backgroundColor ?? .white

Comment: No! You set colors for words “First controller” - red, “Second controller” - green, “Third controller” - violet, like on your screen! Where you set this colors ?

Comment: @alexleo check first 2 lines of printMessage method

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
let text = "This is a colorful attributed string"
let attributedText = 
NSMutableAttributedString.getAttributedString(fromString: text)
attributedText.apply(color: .red, subString: "This")
//Apply yellow color on range
attributedText.apply(color: .yellow, onRange: NSMakeRange(5, 4))


For more detail click here: https://github.com/iOSTechHub/AttributedString
```

Comment: Is this a universal solution for all Controllers or I need apply this for each(I have 3) ?

Comment: It's specific to one view controller. You can apply it to all of them in one of several ways: 1) Put the logic in a base view controller and make your 3 view controllers subclass it; 2) Subclass `UITextView` to apply the changes when its `text` attribute is set, and then use the subclassed text view in all 3 view controllers; 3) put this in a utility function that all 3 view controllers can call; etc.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
firstTextView.textColor = UIColor.red
```

Apply this on viewDidLoad() for each ViewController.

Change the color to whatever you want.

Comment: Have you tried your answer on a `UITextView` with `NSAttributedString`s?